# Instantiation of static template member function?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, stdbind

I have a problem, given this snippet of code:

```
class Thread{
    private:
    template<class t_Funtion, class ... t_Args>
    struct ThreadExiter
    {
        using CallbackType = decltype(std::bind(std::declval<t_Funtion>(), std::declval<t_Args>()...));

        static CallbackType m_Callback;

        template<class ... t_ConstructorArgs>
        ThreadExiter(t_Funtion p_Function, t_ConstructorArgs ... p_Args) :
            m_Callback(std::forward<t_Funtion>(p_Function), std::forward<t_ConstructorArgs&&>(p_Args) ...)
        {
            // Nothing to do
        }
        ~ThreadExiter()
        {
            m_Callback();
        }
    };
```

How can I instantiate the static member `static CallbackType m_Callback;` ?

I tried:

```
template<class t_Funtion, class ... t_Args> 
typename Thread::ThreadExiter<t_Funtion, t_Args...>::CallbackType Thread::ThreadExiter<t_Funtion, t_Args...>::m_Callback
```

But I got:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::_Bind<int (*(Thread*)) Thread*)>::_Bind()'  typename Thread::ThreadExiter<t_Funtion, t_Args...>::CallbackType Thread::ThreadExiter<t_Funtion, t_Args...>::m_Callback;
                                                               ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you! In the end I resolved in this way (cause I didn't have copy and assignment constructor):

```
     static CallbackType* m_Callback;
        template<class ... t_ConstructorArgs>
        ThreadExiter(t_Funtion p_Function, t_ConstructorArgs ... p_Args)
        {
            static CallbackType l_Callback(std::forward<t_Funtion>(p_Function), std::forward<t_ConstructorArgs&&>(p_Args) ...);
            m_Callback = &l_Callback;
        }

        ~ThreadExiter()
        {
            m_Callback->operator()();
        }
```

Instantiated this way:

```
Template<class t_Funtion, class ... t_Args>
using CallbackType = decltype(std::bind(std::declval<t_Funtion>(), 
std::declval<t_Args>()...));

template<class t_Funtion, class ... t_Args>
CallbackType<t_Funtion, t_Args...>* Thread::ThreadExiter<t_Funtion, t_Args...>::m_Callback;
```

Answer (score 1):

You err when trying to construct a static member in the constructor of `ThreadExiter`:

```
ThreadExiter(/*...*/) : m_Callback(/*...*/) {}
```

Here yo go:

```
class Thread
{
private:
    template<class t_Funtion, class ... t_Args>
    struct ThreadExiter
    {
        using CallbackType = decltype(std::bind(std::declval<t_Funtion>(), std::declval<t_Args>()...));

        static CallbackType m_Callback;

        template<class ... t_ConstructorArgs>
        ThreadExiter(t_Funtion p_Function, t_ConstructorArgs ... p_Args)
        {
            m_Callback = CallbackType{std::forward<t_Funtion>(p_Function), std::forward<t_ConstructorArgs&&>(p_Args) ...};
        }
        ~ThreadExiter()
        {
            m_Callback();
        }
    };
};

template<class t_Funtion, class ... t_Args> 
typename Thread::ThreadExiter<t_Funtion, t_Args...>::CallbackType Thread::ThreadExiter<t_Funtion, t_Args...>::m_Callback;
```